# why is minority interest included in enterprise value?

Tags: corporate-acquisition

Per Investopedia (http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/ev-ebitda.asp):

Enterprise Value = (market capitalization) + (value of debt) + (minority interest) + (preferred shares) - (cash and cash equivalents)

I understand why debt and preferred shares would be counted in EV (and cash/cash equivalents counted against it) since EV represents a theoretical takeover cost.

However, I don't understand why minority interest would be added to EV. The value of such shares would already be included in market capitalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US accounting rules require companies that own more than 50% of subsidiaries to consolidate those subsidiaries onto their own books. But if it's more than 50% but not a wholly-owned subsidiary, then there's an entry on the parent company balance sheet for the value of the subsidiary *not* controlled by the parent (the Minority Interest) to adjust for that less-than-full ownership of the subsidiary.

In other words, it's not already incorporated into Market Cap because it's not part of the parent company's equity (ditto for debt). There's a useful  and more [detailed explanation here](http://www.ibankingfaq.com/interviewing-technical-questions/enterprise-value-and-equity-value/what-is-minority-interest-and-why-is-it-in-the-enterprise-value-formula/).